# Coq inductive reasoning about ACSL inductive predicates?

Tags: coq, frama-c, formal-verification, why3

Is it possible to use induction on inductive predicates defined in ACSL?

Consider the following example from the [ACSL manual](http://frama-c.com/download/acsl.pdf):

```
struct List {
    int value;
    struct List* next;
};
/*@ inductive reachable{L}(struct List* root, struct List* to) {
  @   case empty{L}: \forall struct List* l; reachable(l, l);
  @   case non_empty{L}: \forall struct List *l1,*l2;
  @     \valid(l1) && reachable(l1->next, l2) ==> reachable(l1, l2);
  @ }
*/
```

I am trying to prove the following lemma:

```
/*@ lemma next_null_reachable: \forall struct List* l;
  @   \valid(l) && reachable(l, \null) ==> reachable(l->next, \null);
*/
```

Alt-Ergo fails here, so I resort to manual Coq reasoning:

```
Goal
  forall (t : array Z),
  forall (t_1 : farray addr addr),
  forall (a : addr),
  ((valid_rw t a 2%Z)) ->
  ((P_reachable t t_1 a (null))) ->
  ((P_reachable t t_1 (t_1.[ (shiftfield_F_List_next a) ]) (null))).
```

But when I `Search P_reachable`, I find only two axioms generated:

```
Q_non_empty:
  forall (t : array int) (t_1 : farray addr addr) (a_1 a : addr),
  valid_rw t a_1 2 ->
  P_reachable t t_1 (t_1 .[ shiftfield_F_List_next a_1]) a ->
  P_reachable t t_1 a_1 a
Q_empty:
  forall (t : array int) (t_1 : farray addr addr) (a : addr),
  P_reachable t t_1 a a
```

And no induction principle. So I can not apply `induction P_reachable` or `destruct P_reachable`.

I use WP plugin of `frama-c` version Sodium-20150201.

To reproduce, you could run `frama-c -wp -wp-rte -wp-prover coqide file.c`, where `file.c` contains the `List` and `reachable` definitions and the `next_null_reachable` lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the form of your goals, I'm assuming you're using the WP plugin. Indeed, it does not provide a lemma indicating that `reachable` is the smallest predicate verifying the two cases `empty` and `non_empty`, meaning that you can't use induction.

If I remember correctly, adding such an axiom would confuse first-order theorem provers (who would repeatedly construct instances of `reachable` through `empty` or `non_empty` and destruct them with the induction principle). However, the Coq output of WP could very well provide a complete translation.

A workaround is to provide an appropriate set of specialized lemmas (that will not be provable through WP) instead of the induction principle. See e.g. `binary_search_proved.c` in [this archive](https://bts.frama-c.com/dokuwiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=mantis:frama-c:tutorial:lifo-2014:solutions.tar.gz).

Answer (score 0):

I never used Alt-Ergo, but it seems that they don't create real inductive proposition, but rather axiomatize them. So you can't do `induction` but you can use the basic blocks they provide (`Q_empty` is your default constructor and `Q_non_empty` is your inductive constructor) to perform the proof.

I lack some basic definitions to replay your problem, but I would go by applying `Q_non_empty` once, which should ask me to prove a `valid_rw` statement and a sub `P_reachable` statement. They both should be provable using your context.

Comment: I updated the question with sufficient reproduction information. But I do not believe that you will be able to prove it as it is, because Q_non_empty is constructive, basically it witnesses reachable(l->next, \null) => reachable(l, \null); while I need an opposite hypothesis here.